# Redoing old git setup

Tags: git, github

Now that my git knowledge has improved, I have decided to redo a git setup I have for a website I'm running. (What I'm about to describe is terrible practice)

I have 3 'locations': Local, Production (dedicated web server) and Github. I want to add a new location; Test Server. Currently only my local pc is running git (and github of course). As I worked on the php files I would save them and Netbeans would upload them to the production server. There I would see if it worked or not. If it did I would commit them and push them to github. I now want to install git on the production server and I want to add a Test server also running git. So I can do the following:

Work on the code, push them to the dev branch, pull dev branch on test server. Test, merge into master. Pull on production server from master.

How would I go about setting all of this up without breaking anything. The production server contains 100% up to date files. I don't want to lose my commits. I have a feeling I should just install git on the production server, commit and pull on all other locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply cloning the repo on all the servers. Adding some tweaks to the config files to get everything up to date and committed all those tweaks. Everything is working as it should